# Using ComputeIfAbsent in HashMap

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I have read similar posts on this, but is this a right way to use computeIfAbsent function? cookieMap is a HashMap and responses is an Object which contains all the headers, cookies, responses, status Code etc...

```
cookieMap.computeIfAbsent("Varlink", varLink -> {
  if (responses.getCookie("VARLINK").length() < 1) {
    throw new ProviderException("Varlink not present in response, check response status!!!");
  }
  return responses.getCookie("VARLINK");
});
```

I will need to add multiple keys like this to the cookieMap. My initial thought was to put everything inside an If condition, but due to certain restrictions we are not supposed to have nested if-else conditions (I guess the Code Reviewer took the book Clean Code too seriously)

Comment: Hard to tell.  What is `cookieMap`?  `computeIfAbsent` is used to retrieve a value in a map, and to provide initialization mechanism if no value for the provided key is present.

Comment: It's HashMap<String, String>

Comment: How is it used, what is the point/relevance of it?  Why are you using computeIfAbsent?  Is there a possibility the value could be there?

Comment: Assuming that `cookieMap` and `respones` are different maps, there is nothing wrong with this usage, but it’s recommended to store the result of `respones.getCookie("VARLINK")` into a local variable, instead of evaluating the same expression twice. Further, you may consider moving the code of the lambda’s body into a named method (that will make most code reviewers happy) and use a method reference or a simple `varLink -> expression` lambda expression in `computeIfAbsent`.

Comment: @Holger thanks for the answer. `responses` is an object which has all the cookies, header and response of the request. What I finally did was 
`cookieMap.put("VARLINK",
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(respones.getCookie("VARLINK"),
            "Varlink not present in Response, check Response status!!!"));` Turns out the `response` object returns a `null` if the key is not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `responses` and `cookieMap` are two different sources of data, then your snippet is correct. The only concern is calling `cookieMap::getCookie` twice which might be resolved using a variable as someone has suggested in the comments.

I'd shorten the entire expression using `Optional` to:

```
cookieMap.computeIfAbsent("Varlink", v -> {
    Optional.of(respones.getCookie("VARLINK"))                // Gets a cookie
            .filter(c -> c.length() >= 1)                     // Filters the length
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ProviderException("...")); // Returns only if present
});
```

Comment: Yes responses and cookeMap are two different sources of data. Thanks for the approach though, it's good. As mentioned in the comment above, for my actual code I used Preconditions (Guava).